# Implement onclick on dynamic item of viewfillper android

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am trying to add click listner on my `viewflipper` which contains dynamic image. but i am unable to implement click listener for image inside the view flipper. how can i do that? i searched in this site and did not help my self:
below is my code sample:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < post.getImages().size(); i++) {
            ImageView image = new ImageView(MyActivity.this);
            Picasso.get().load(room.getImages().get(i)).into(image);
            viewFlipper.addView(image);}
```

(P.S. I want click listener for my images)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `viewFlipper.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(..)` inside your for loop.

`getChildAt(int index)` : Returns the view at the specified position in the `viewflipper`.

see [docs for more viewgroup's implementation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup)